# Java Transformer: How do you make its result into an OutputStream?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, dom, transformation

I am new to `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`.

I am applying an `XSLT` on an `XML` document and It works fine.

What I want to achieve is to be able to write the output of that tranformation to an `OutputStream`.

This is my code:

```
OutputStream outputStream = null;
InputStream agent = new FileInputStream("src/res/testxmlfile.xml");
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("src/res/trans.xslt"));
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(agent), outputStream ????????);
```

I know it can be used to write a file like this, but I want to write it to a  `OutputStream` Object.

```
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(agent),
                      new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("/result.xml")));
```

How can I pass an `OutputStream` to be used here?

This is the error I am getting when I am passing the `Outputstream`:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:
                            Result object passed to ''{0}'' is invalid.
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl
                           .getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:468)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl
                           .transform(TransformerImpl.java:344)
at com.gohealth.TestXmlStream.main(TestXmlStream.java:75)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `StreamResult`. It provides constructors to write to a `File` or an `OutputStream`:

Example using `File`:

```
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(agent), new StreamResult(file));
```

Example using `FileOutputStream`:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("outputfile.xml"));
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(agent), new StreamResult(outputStream));
```

Example using `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(agent), new StreamResult(outputStream));
byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();`
```

Comment: When I try to use
OutputStream outputStream = null;
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(agent), new StreamResult(outputStream))

I get a exception:
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Result object passed to ''{0}'' is invalid.
 at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:468)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:344)
 at com.gohealth.TestXmlStream.main(TestXmlStream.java:75)

Comment: You need to initialize your `outputStream`. It is still `null` in your case. Will add some examples on how to initialize a couple types of `OutputStream`s.

Comment: Thank you very much for guiding me, the above solution works for me. I am new to Streams and I don't have experience working with them. Any recommendation where I should look for to learn quickly? Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Use a "StreamResult" constructed with an object that represents where you want the output.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamResult.html